# pg_stat_activity aggregated data for monitoring in json

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have to summarize data in pg_stat_activity and return it as json. Postgres 9.3 onboard. The result needed is smth like:

```
{
  "web": 67,
  "postgres": 2,
  "totalSessions": 69,
  "idle in transaction": 2,
  "active": 1,
  "idle": 66
}
```

where active is the number of active sessions, idle - of idle, total - the sum of both and the rest is number of sessions per user. We did not need to group it by databases, but principle would be the same.

No - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The qry I came up with is no better then:

```
mon=# with pre as (
  select  DISTINCT
    concat('"totalSessions":',sum(count(1)) over (),'') total
  , concat('"',usename,'":',sum(count(1)) over (partition by usename),'') u
  , concat('"',state,'":',sum(count(1)) over (partition by state),'') s
  from pg_stat_activity
  group by state,usename
)
  select concat('{',string_agg(j,','),'}')::json from (
    select distinct u j from pre u
    union all
    select distinct total from pre s
    union all
    select distinct s from pre s
  ) pg_stat_act
;
                                          concat
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"web":67,"postgres":2,"totalSessions":69,"idle in transaction":2,"active":1,"idle":66}
(1 row)

Time: 1.807 ms
```